# How do I get started with Tridion as a developer accessing content?

Tags: core-service, sdl-tridion

We have a Tridion installation and I need to setup a web service that will retrieve content from it.  I've been to the community and documentation web site but haven't found anything about how to get started with Tridion as a Java developer that has to retrieve content from it.  Most of the links that I've found through web searches are no longer valid.

I'd appreciate any pointers to how to get started with Tridion as a developer in 2019.

Comment: One thing that always trips people is that Tridion is a multi-headed system - there's Content and there's _published_ content. Which one are you trying to access? If you want to access content published from Tridion for a web application, you probably need Content Delivery rather Content Management/Core Service as some answers imply here.

Comment: I will be creating a REST web service that the client (Angular) calls.  My web service will retrieve content from Tridion that will be displayed on the web site.  That sounds like Content Delivery, but it's not clear what the difference is between Content Delivery and Content Management/Core Services is.  What are the use cases for each?

Answer (score 2):

Take in a look in the docs for Core Service, which is an OOTB web service API to retrieve raw content from the CMS (not for website rendering, but for internal operations). Also in the docs search for keywords  Content Delivery service, CIS and CIL - this is the serrivce for retrieving published content for website rendering.

Comment: Thanks, but where do I find documentation?  I can't find anything on the sdl website.  When I search for Tridion documentation I get marketing brochures.

Comment: Found it.  I'll post for others:  https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%202013%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-840A61DA-AEAD-444D-B7F3-104578841C20

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** Please review Nuno’s comment before reading this answer. This answer relates to getting content (and other items) in and out of the CMS, rather than rendering published content on your website.

---

As Nick says, you’ll want to use the Core Service to get content (and other items) in and out of the CMS itself.

As well as the SDL documentation link that you posted as a comment, you may also want to take a look at the **Core Service Recipes** in the Tridion Cookbook:
https://github.com/TridionPractice/tridion-practice/wiki/CookbookDocumentation

This includes things such as configuring the Core Service and some basic scripts on working with content and metadata.

There are also a lot of helpful questions and answers on here under the [core-service] tag (which I’ve added to your question).

Mihai also has a lot of information about using the Core Service with a Java client. I’m not sure how up to date this is though, as it says the last supported version of Tridion is 2013SP1:
http://mihaiconsulting.com/projects/core-service-java

Hope this helps!